# EXPO: Uncaught Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.STANDARD_EVENT_ADD_TO_CART')

Tags: react-native, expo, branch.io

I built a standalone android app in expo and run into this error when running the apk in my physical device. Here is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

How can I debug and solve this issues? I could not find any good reference so far on the internet

Comment: can you specify more details on this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an expo issue, solutions are provided here:

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1552

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3152

Let me know if it is a branch issue!

Comment: Facing this in a pure RN project; app throws this error on launch; wasn't there before branch integration